# Colors in Spyder Variable Explorer

Tags: python, spyder

I am new to Spyder, and for the life of me I can't seem to work out what the background colors indicate on the variable explorer? Apologies, this may sound like a very dumb question if it is obvious, but I have read the help files, and they make no mention of it.

[image: Spyder Variable Explorer Example]

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) The colors are meant to distinguish between different types of variables (numbers, strings, lists, arrays, etc).